# Network link (KML) from GeoServer error - Unable to transform referenced envelope, crs has not yet been provided

Tags: coordinate-system, geoserver, kml-network-link

Every time I download a network link from the GeoServer, I get this error:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?><!DOCTYPE ServiceExceptionReport SYSTEM "___geoserver/schemas/wms/1.1.1/WMS_exception_1_1_1.dtd"> <ServiceExceptionReport version="1.1.1" >   <ServiceException>
      java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NullPointerException: Unable to transform referenced envelope, crs has not yet been provided.
java.lang.NullPointerException: Unable to transform referenced envelope, crs has not yet been provided. 
Unable to transform referenced envelope, crs has not yet been provided\</ServiceException></ServiceExceptionReport>
```

I am able to download a KML (plain) file, however not a KML (network link) because of the above error.

In the Layer: the following parameters have been set:
The Lat/Lon Bounding Box is based on South Africa's bounding box coordinates, and the native bounding box was computed from data.
[image]

The data includes polygons in different locations in South Africa.

Also the KML settings are as below:
[image]

I am not sure why I am unable to get the KML as a network link.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: You need to turn up the logging level to developer in the global settings page, and then make the request again. Then [edit] your question with the **relevant** part of the log file.